# JavaScript - Bar Graph with custom animation fill

Tags: javascript, plot, d3.js

I need to draw a bar graph with custom animated fill which would be different for each bar.

I couldn't find any javascript library that facilitates this. I think I'd have to code it myself.

Can I do this using d3? Or is there any other library which can be modified easily?

Answer (score 1):

Yes,you can create animated bar graph using D3.js with transition() feature.Refer [this blog](http://needforair.com/blog/2012/05/09/d3-tutorial/) for example graph.